# Is it correct to use Newton's third law on all these scenarios?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, inertial-frames, collision, relative-motion

So I was thinking about Newton's third law for sometime lately, and my problem is more about the concept, I'm fine with solving problems.
I thought of these scenarios and tried to apply Newton's three laws on each and now I'm even more confused.
My goal here is to assure if the force experienced by both of the fly and the train is the same  in these scenarios:
For all of these assume a train and a fly facing each other on a certain axis also neglect any external field forces and assume both of the fly and the train as particles(neglect deformation)

- Dynamic fly collides with a static train
- Dynamic train collides with a static fly
- Dynamic train collides with dynamic fly

My answer to these is yes,no,no respectively.
What do you think?

Comment: Why would the first and second not be the same? Aren't the situations identical and just reversed? That being said, when you say "*My goal here is to assure if the force experienced by both of the fly and the train is the same in these scenarios*" then remember that **no force exists alone**. All forces come in an action/reaction pair. They are **never** alone. So that makes it quite easy: if nothing else applies force, then the force on the fly and train must be the same **always**. Regardless of how any of them are moving at that moment.

Comment: To my understanding the train is capable of applying a force equal to the fly's while the fly isn't capable of doing the same, I mean for the second and third ones my guess is that there will be a resulting net force in the direction of the train which is F(net) =F(Train) - F(fly),(sorry for not using mathjax)

Comment: I think yes, yes, yes. One way to think of it is that the physical laws are the same in all intertal frames. This is not maybe not the first thing one learn in physics, and may sound abstract, but it is a very powerful tool!

Comment: @user597368. I think you've been caught in a typical misunderstanding. Let me ask you this: Here you added up the forces to give the net force because you are using Newton's 2nd law. Newton's 2nd law tells us that the forces on *an object* (or system) sum up to cause the acceleration *of that object*. Now, which object are you summing up the forces for? Which object are you doing Newton's 2nd law on?

Comment: In this case I'm doing it on a train with a fly stuck onto it., this confuses me even more, I'm just trying to imagine it

Comment: the law is universal, so the answer is yes in the three scenarions

Comment: @user597368, the train can't put a force on the fly if the fly doesn't push against the train.  This is true regardless of the size differences between the train and the fly.  I realize that Newton's 3rd law is non-intuitive.  I also realize that *everyone* knows that the bigger object puts more force on the smaller object, but this common sense concept is just plain incorrect.  At some point, you need to discard the misconception and accept Newton's 3rd law as fact.

Comment: we cannot help you more because you did not explain whi you think it does not apply in 2 and 3

Comment: @user597368, one more comment.  When I was teaching high school physics, I went over several examples just like the fly-train problem, and students seemed to understand the concept on that particular day.  However, INVARIABLY, there were some students who reverted back to their misconceptions on test day, and missed the Newton's 3rd law questions on the test.  Some people just want to hold onto their misconceptions, even when they have direct evidence to the contrary in front of them.  You can't properly learn physics is you insist on doing this.

Comment: @Wolphram jonny, I did explain my choice in the comments section, at David white: I think I get it now I think this is analogous to the forces between the moon and earth and why doesn't the earth pull the moon into the ground; this is physics indeed, I didn't  insist I was just trying to stabilise the concept correctly in my brain with out memorising whats and not knowing hows, any way thank you Steeven,B. Brekke, Wolphram, David, Bob for helping, have a cheerful day

Comment: @user597368 Why the earth and moon do not collide has nothing to do with Newton's third law

Comment: I think you didn't get what I've said, I mean it's the same principle as even thought the earth has more mass than the moon both experience the same force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, yes, and yes.

The problem is that your comment ***“To my understanding the train is capable of applying a force equal to the fly's while the fly isn't capable of doing the same”*** to Steeven is incorrect. The forces are equal and opposite, but obviously the effect of the forces are not. Before considering the three scenarios, consider the following.

Let the force on the fly be $F_{fly}$. The acceleration of the fly is then related to $F_{fly}$ by Newton’s second law,

$$F_{fly}=m_{fly}a_{fly}$$

And the acceleration of the train is related to the force on the train, $F_{train}$ by Newton's second law,

$$F_{train}=M_{train}a_{train}$$

From Newton’s third law,

$$F_{train}=-F_{fly}$$

Therefore

$$m_{fly}a_{fly}=- M_{train}a_{train}$$

And

$$a_{train}=-\frac{m_{fly}a_{fly}}{M_{train}}$$

$$a_{fly}=-\frac{M_{train}a_{train}}{m_{fly}}$$

Since $M_{train}>>>m_{fly}$, $a_{train}<<<a_{fly}$ and the affect of the fly on the train is miniscule compared to the effect of the train on the fly.

Now let’s consider the three scenarios

***-Dynamic fly collides with a static train***

Based on the equation for the acceleration of the fly, the dynamic fly undergoes a large deceleration compared to the train's acceleration upon impacting the static train. Based on the equation for the acceleration of the train, the static train undergoes a miniscule acceleration compared to that of the fly due to the impact of the dynamic fly.

***-Dynamic train collides with a static fly***

Based on the equation for the acceleration of the train, the dynamic train undergoes a miniscule deceleration compared to that of the fly upon impacting the static fly. Based on the equation for the acceleration of the fly, the static fly undergoes a large acceleration compared to the acceleration of the train due to the impact by the dynamic train.

***-Dynamic train collides with dynamic fly***

The equations still apply but what happens will depend the relative velocities of the fly and the train. For example, if they are both going in the same direction, and the velocities are nearly the same, the force each imposes on the other will be small (and the fly might even survive!).

After the fly and train collide and stick together, the two objects can be considered as one and will have the same acceleration $a$ where $a$ is

$$a=\frac{F}{m+M}$$

And $F$ is the external force applied to combination of the train and the fly.

Bottom line, Newton’s third law does not nullify Newton’s second law. Newton’s second law applies to each object individually. Newton’s third law simply means that forces do not exist in isolation.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think I'm close to getting it, thanks. So does this mean that for the first case the train is going to get accelerated and probably move towards the fly even if for an infitesimal time, also a side note that I denoted that both of the fly and train face each other (so they would move toward each other in the third case) but I think this still follows the same pattern of deceleration for the train and acceleration for the fly.

Comment: @user597368 Yes the train gets accelerated but given the ratio of the masses it would be for all practical purposes immeasurable. Sorry I  missed the side note.